# problem while changing col names with str_to_title

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

It can be build using codes:

```
df<- structure(list(`Med` = c("DOCETAXEL", 
"BEVACIZUMAB", "CARBOPLATIN", "CETUXIMAB", "DOXORUBICIN", "IRINOTECAN"
), `2.4 mg` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `PRIOR CANCER THERAPY` = c(4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), `PRIOR CANCER SURGERY` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `PRIOR RADIATION THERAPY` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I would like to change col name that are not start with number to proper case. How should I do it? I thought I could use `str_to_title`. I have tried many ways can not get it to work. Here is the codes that I tried:

```
# try1:
df[,3:5] %>% setNames(str_to_title(colnames(df[,3:5])))

#try2:
df[,3:5] <- df[,3:5]%>% rename_with (str_to_title)

# try3:
colnames(df[,3:5])<- str_to_title(colnames(df[,3:5]))
```

What did I do wrong? there is no error message, just the col names did not get updated. Could anyone help me identify the issue, or maybe show me a better way if you have?

Here I have small data then I can find the col number. If I want it to auto correct the col names to proper case, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   rename_at(3:5, ~ str_to_title(.))
```

-output

```
#         Med 2.4 mg Prior Cancer Therapy Prior Cancer Surgery Prior Radiation Therapy
#1   DOCETAXEL      0                    4                    0                       0
#2 BEVACIZUMAB      0                    3                    0                       0
#3 CARBOPLATIN      0                    3                    0                       0
#4   CETUXIMAB      0                    3                    0                       0
#5 DOXORUBICIN      1                    3                    0                       0
#6  IRINOTECAN      0                    3                    0                       0
```

---

Or using `rename_with`

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_to_title(.), 3:5)
```